# Problems returning cshtml (razor) using PartialView in controller?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm just getting started with the Razor view engine. I've upgraded an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project using the upgrade program [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/07/28/migrating-asp-net-mvc-2-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx).  The upgrade seems to have been successful since I'm able to create new views using the Razor view engine and intellisense works with the @ syntax.

I have renamed an existing partial view from "PageView.ascx" to "PageView.cshtml"

However, in my controller when I try to return the partial view like:

```
return PartialView("PageView", model);
```

I get a server error saying that the view could not be found.  The search paths listed in the error message all end with PageView.ascx or .aspx.

I have created a ASP.NET MVC 3.0 test application from scratch and the scenario above does not generate an error - it finds PageView.cshtml without issue.  I've also copied the web.config from the Views folder of the working project to the Views folder of my project that is not working.

Did i miss a configuration step somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are not doing anything with the `ViewEngineCollection` in yout Global.asax files.

Comment: I had ViewEngines.Engines.Clear() in the Application_Start in Global.asax.  removing it fixed the problem.  Thanks!